# Сдвинуть всё вниз (добавить margin)

Tags: css

Здраствуйте. Вот проблемка вышла. Создаю (копирую) сборник приложений в WPI (windows post-install wizard), и мне нужно сдвинуть все элементы вниз на 200 пикселей на главном меня. Помогите если знаете как это сделать. Я порылся в .css файлах и добавлял там margin но не помогло.
[Вот фото](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnndr.jpg)

Comment: 1. Плохо. что вы не предоставили вашу вёрстку, да и скриншот прикручен лишь как внешняя ссылка. 2. margin указывает внешние отступы у всего блока, то есть на указанное расстояние съезжает весь блок и в указанном ниже ответе сдвигается целиком body. Если бы вы указали вёрстку, можно было бы точнее понять, какой блок внутри body следует сдвинуть вниз, чтобы это не влияло на фоновую картинку. 3. Попробуйте `margin-top: 200px;` заменить на `padding-top: 200px;`. padding добавляет внутренние отступы в блоке. Лучше всего всё-таки приведите ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сдвинуть всё вниз то попробуйте сделать так.

```css
body{
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: я это попробовал, и это сработало но вниз ушло и бекграунд фото. Вот мне надо сдвинуть кроме него все элементы